# How to run JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

In Chrome, I right clicked and select "inspect", and then I went "Console" tab. I wanted to practice JavaScript, so I typed

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

and hit enter, but I got error message

> Uncaught Syntax error: Unexpected Token<

Why?

Comment: What are you trying to practice? We can run JavaScript code easy in console

Comment: That is a script tag, which is HTML.  You can't run HTML in the console.  That tag *contains* JavaScript, after the close of the tag in the question until the closing tag `</script>`.

Comment: You can not run it in the console. `<script>` is a **HTML** tag.

Answer (score 1):

The console defaults to run javascript so you need not specify

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

this explicitly it understands so just try to run the javascript as it is and it should be working fine.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm learning Javascript. Here I skipped
<script type="text/javascript"> and just typed "document.write("Hello World!");", but I got "Undefined" returned in the console. So do I need to define anything before using the function?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following website for JS practice

> https://jsfiddle.net

Coming to your question, you can practice JS in Console but you don't need to tell browser that you want to run javascript it know by default.

And `<script>` is a tag in HTML, read about it here https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_scripts.asp.

Answer (score 0):

Easy Way :

1. Create HTML file named as index.html in folder( say javascript).
2. Create another file name it as script.js .
3. Write script tag in tag of index.html
4. Run the index.html file in google chrome.
5. Press Ctrl+Alt+I .
6. Click on Console .